# How to use the phone's speakers and microphone during calls, but use the headset for all other sounds?

Tags: calls, headset

When making calls I prefer using the phone itself instead of my headset. Is it possible to configure Android to do so? I'm using a rooted phone with Android 9.0 if it matters.

There are solutions online for how to disable the headset microphone, but not for disabling the speakers of the headset as well during calls.